# Activity on Pets.SE

Tags: support, questions, site-evaluation, users, recent-activity

I have joined this almost a month ago and had a lot of fun answering people's cuddly creature questions; however, it seems that activity on the site has plummeted to only two questions a day. Why is this and how can it be fixed? I want to answer people's questions.

Comment: I have an answer to a related question on the main meta that may be of interest https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363503/879421 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity of many of the smaller SE sites in my experience does fluctuate quite a bit. Often you can see seasons or the average user base’s activities reflected in the posts (you’d be surprised about the number of turkey questions that are either asked or answered between November and December on Cooking SE).

Increasing attention for small sites is a recurring topic on the smaller sites and I am not sure anyone has found the magic formula yet. Events like elections do tend to gain some attention (which then translates to posts) within the SE network. Outside, it’s difficult to say - and not all media attention is or was good.

As you enjoy answering questions, let me suggest a few ideas, which I have all practiced when the influx of questions was low.

- **Go through your own posts and improve them.**
  Have you learned something new that could make the post better? Can you add references? Improve readability (although we do have a few *very* enthusiastic editors here that tend to diligently work on grammar, spelling and formatting)?
- **Ask and self-answer questions.**
  Think of it as adding useful content to the site in general. If you remember that SE is designed as a knowledge-base that should serve not just the current answer,  but ideally multiple future readers, that’s a helpful thing to do. When a new site starts out in Area 51, these Q/A pairs help shape the proposed site.
- **Expand your activities to other ways of contributing**.
  All SE communities depend on their user base to work the review questions, improve posts, vote, guide new users, write tag descriptions... see what [privileges](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you have and use them.

If I may add a personal suggestion after looking at the votes on your previous answers, I would recommend starting with the first point.